# (HTML) My navbar glitches and doesnt let me click on of the drop down items

Tags: html, css, navbar

When i hover over one of my tool bar or navBar items to click on the children links it dissapears before i can click one. How to fix this glitch? Ive tried editing my css, html, and messing around with the padding as well.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -0.69px;
  /*works a little bit better*/
}

body {
  background-color: #BBBCC0;
  height: 1350px;
}

hr {
  border-color: black;
}

#homeB2_fig {
  left: 575px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#homeB2_figCap {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#mail {
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
}

#facebook {
  position: relative;
  left: 535px;
}

#twitter {
  position: relative;
  left: 545px;
}

#donate {
  position: relative;
  top: -95px;
  left: 675px;
}

#calendarFig {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -400px;
  left: -400px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#calendarFigCap {
  position: relative;
  top: -45px
}

#minnesotaFig {
  position: relative;
  top: -700px;
  left: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#minnesotaFigCap {
  position: relative;
  top: 7.5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#Heading_home {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -175px;
}

#home_para {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -130px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: serif;
}

#logoLeft {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: -109px;
}

#logoRight {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 834px;
}

#otherChapters_p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#calendar {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -400px;
}

#minessota {
  position: relative;
  left: 750px;
  top: -450px;
}

#minnesotaP {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#second {
  position: relative;
  top: -700px;
}

#contactUsHeader {
  position: relative;
  top: -680px;
  left: 490px;
}

#contactUs {
  position: relative;
  top: -680px;
  left: 465px;
}

#hoursHeader {
  position: relative;
  top: -960px;
  left: 900px;
}

#hours {
  position: relative;
  top: -960px;
  left: 880px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rtsnp_home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rtsnp_navBar.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="rtsnp_home.html">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">About Us
              <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="rtsnp_missionStatement.html">Mission Statement</a>
        <a href="ourFounder.html">Our Founder</a>
        <a href="#">Our Board of Directors</a>
        <a href="#">National Board of Directors</a>
        <a href="#">Programs Offered</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Our Athletes
              <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Ring of Honor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img id="logoLeft" src="icon.png" alt="rtsnp logo" style="width: 375px; height: 200px;">
  <img id="logoRight" src="iconFlip.png" alt="rtsnp logo" style="wdith: 375px; height: 200px;">
  <h1 id="Heading_home">Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program</h1>
  <p id="home_para">Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program is one of the first inclusive running clubs in the USA for all athletes. Founded in 1998 by Steve Cuomo, the Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program (RTSNP) is a one of a kind nonprofit (501c3) organization dedicated
    to providing challenged individuals with the opportunity to successfully participate in all levels of mainstream running, walking, or wheelchair racing. We are a member of Long Island Track and Field, and its parent organization, USA Track and Field.<br><br>What
    else makes Rolling Thunder unique? The entire family can exercise and improve their physical fitness at the same time in the same place! Several families are members of Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program. Parents and siblings of challenged individuals
    become acquainted, share experiences, and may become great friends. Check out our About Us page to learn more.</p>

  <a type=href="https://www.paypal.com/donate/?token=1RuxEJjfaRGzVXtVa3yehGsV-2X04iefjn1KGd-CuSrPpFyT8iEvC3ZhJKep5RNzJeBxlW&country.x=US&locale.x=US">
    <input id="donate" type="image" src="donate.gif" value="go donate">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Rolling-Thunder-Special-Needs-Program-RTSNP-123816781047514/?fref=ts">
    <input id="facebook" type="image" src="facebook.png" value="go to facebook">
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/rtsnp">
    <input id="twitter" type="image" src="twitter.png" value="go to twitter">
  </a>
  <hr>
  <figure id="homeB2_fig">
    <img src="homeB2.jpg" alt="RED" width="304" height="228">
    <figcaption id="homeB2_figCap">Rolling Thunder Chapters</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p id="otherChapters_p">Chapters of the Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program are developing across the USA. If you would like to start a Rolling Thunder Chapter, please contact the Founder, President and Head Coach Steve Cuomo at (631)-399-5564.</p>
  <figure id="calendarFig">
    <img src="calendar_2.0.png" alt="LEFT" width="300" height="300">
    <figcaption id="calendarFigCap">Checkout Our New York Calendar</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure id="minnesotaFig">
    <img src="minnesota_2.0.png" alt="LEFT" width="200" height="200">
    <figcaption id="minnesotaFigCap">Welcome Our Newest Rolling Thunder Chapter: Minnesota!</figcaption>
    <p id="minnesotaP">Rolling Thunder adopted Minnesota as it’s newest chapter as it was much need. There are well over 7 Athletes to this new chapter and well over 10 coaches and volunteers. If you would like to get involved with the Rolling Thunder Minnesota Chapter
      please contact President Claire Braun at (763)-742-3286</p>
  </figure>
  <hr id="second">
  <h3 id="contactUsHeader">Contact Us</h3>
  <p id="contactUs">Rolling Thunder Special Needs Program Inc.<br> National Headquarters <br>Beth Cuomo <br> 49 Lombardy Drive <br>Shirley, New York 11967<br> USA <br><br><br>Steve Cuomo <br>Founder, President & Head Coach<br>Cell: (631)-399-5564 <br>Email: nyinfo@rtsnp.org</p>
  <h3 id="hoursHeader">Business Hours</h3>
  <p id="hours">Monday - Thursday | 8:00 AM ET - 6:00 PM ET <br>Friday - Saturday | 8:00 AM ET - 5:00 PM ET </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please consider reducing the code to just enough to replicate the problem, this will help you and us. [MCVE] are awesome, you can use the `<>` button in the editor to provide an interactive example in your question.

Comment: Running all your code together doesn't replicate the issue for me in Chrome 65.0.3325.181, is there additional CSS that may cause this issue? Can you embed an example or link to a working example for us?

Comment: Running all your code together doesn't replicate the issue for me in FireFox 58.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ChandraShekhar why?

Comment: try to reproduce the issue you are facing. so that we can provide the solution.

Comment: @JaanRaadik It happens sometimes not 100% of the time, but it does happen often enough for it to be a problem